# Magento 2.4 - Build Child Theme parent of theme installed via composer

Tags: themes, magento2

I need a tip.
I've installed a theme via composer and I need to create a child theme having as parent a theme installed via composer.

path of theme installed via composer: vendor/{vendor}/{theme}/
path of child theme: app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/

in the child theme folder i've created:
**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>TitleTheme</title>
    <parent>{folder-name-vendor}/{folder-name-theme}</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "{my-vendor-folder}/{my-child-theme}",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/{my-vendor-folder}/{my-child-theme}',
    __DIR__
);
```

When I change the theme from the magento backend panel under
Content > Design > Configuration
and then run:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

It does not load me the parent theme I have chosen, but the default magento theme.I don't know what I'm wrong.
Can someone help me?
Thank you ;)